# Angular2 routing : redirectTo a relative url

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

All is in the title : **can you use the `redirectTo` property to redirect to a relative URL ?**

My (simplified) routing is as follows :

```
{path: 'login', children: []},
{path: '', children: [ // made here for future guards
    {path: 'admin', children: [
        {path: 'dashboard', children: []}
        {path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard'}
    ]}
]},
{path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'}
```

My routing is working well, except that when I want to reach `URL/admin/` an error occurs saying that dashboard is unknown. But, with `redirectTo: 'admin/dashboard'` the routing works.

So is there a way to use relative routing with `rediretcTo` ?

**EDIT** Whole routes :

**app.module**

```
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, children: [] },
{ path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent, children: [] },
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
...loggedRoutes
```

**logged.module**

```
{ path: 'logged', component: LoggedComponent, children: [
{ path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, children: [] },
    ...adminRoutes,
    ...mainRoutes
] },
```

**admin.module**

```
{ path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, children: [
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, children: [] },
    { path: 'validation/:objectid', component: ValidationComponent, children: [] },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/logged/admin/dashboard' },
] },
```

**main.module**

```
{ path: 'main', component: MainComponent, children: [
    { path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent, children: [] },
    { path: 'last', component: LastComponent, children: [] },
    { path: 'process', component: ProcessComponent, children: [] },
    { path: 'crt', component: CrtComponent, children: [] },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/logged/main/error' },
] },
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add `pathMatch: 'full'` to your redirect route and it should work as you intendet it to.

```
{path: 'login', children: []},
{path: '', children: [ // made here for future guards
    {path: 'admin', children: [
        {path: 'dashboard', children: []}
        {path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'} // <-- ADDED here
    ]}
]},
{path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'}
```

Comment: I already tried that and it didn't work. Apparently, when add pathMatch, the URL needs to be totally equal to the parameter. I expected to have a `suffix` like there is a prefix, but unfortunately, it's not the case.

Comment: would you mind posting your whole routes array? For me it works that way... But maybe its because you've got two options for an empty path on the same level, try to put the `admin` path on the same level as `login`. You can add your guards also there in the future.

Comment: path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard'  - it works (angular7)